# Youtube video stop when I close popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When I click on close button, I stopped video but it changed the video URL too. and when I open any popup after closing, all popup's showing 1 video.

this the javascript code which I am working

```js
    var videoSRC = jQuery('.hide_overlay iframe').attr('src');
    jQuery('.close_me').click(function (e) {
      jQuery('.hide_overlay iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple popups? If so, the code to change the src will affect all dialogs.

I'm assuing you're changing the SRC to stop the video. Also, assuming that the `.close_me` element is within the `.hide_overlay` element, you can do this:

```
jQuery('.close_me').click(function (e) {
  var $videoEl = jQuery(this).closest('.hide_overlay').find('iframe');
  $videoEl.attr('src', $videoEl.attr('src'));
});
```

This works because `jQuery(this)` will target the specific close button related to that one popup, and not target all popups.

Technically, a nicer way to stop or pause a video is to use the [Youtube Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) as you can do something like:

`player.stopVideo();`

Comment: Thanks Jeo its working nice now, can you help how to auto start video when popup in open...